# Converting Text To Hexadecimal Flash CS5

Tags: flash-cs5, flash-cs5.5

I am making a colour tester which consist of a background and 3 text box. You can enter the hexadecimal in each of the boxes which will change the background e.g.

_ _ _ 0xF59900 _ _ _

Box1:F5 _ _ _ Box2:99 _ _ _ Box3:00

The top bit where it says "0xF59900" is a text field. How do I convert this to uint so that I can change the background colour.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

var bgColor = "0x123456";
var bgColor:uint = uint(bgColor);